# Working on the formStuff

Tags: android, android-edittext

I was working on the formStuff samples and I am getting a error adding the `EditText`.

This is the line I am getting a error one:

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
```

This is the error:

> Multiple markers at this line
>    - OnKeyListener cannot be resolved to a type
>    - The method setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener)
>   in the type View is not applicable for
>   the    arguments (new
>   OnKeyListener(){})

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your code to View.OnKeyListener from OnKeyListener...or to a particular "View" you want to listen on to the action....

from official Android Documentation following is a setOnKeyListener function signature:

void     setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener l)
Register a callback to be invoked when a key is pressed in this view.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the second error "OnKeyListener cannot be resolved to a type" and the first error will go away.

You need to 
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;